# How do I upgrade from PostGIS 2.0 to 2.1?

Tags: postgis, osx, homebrew

I'm using homebrew on OSX. I have a working postgres 9.2 + postgis 2.0 database installed.

The main problem is that the 9.2 dump contains all the postgis 2.0 tables and functions, which don't need to be imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work & thought it would be helpful to share my notes.

The tricky part was exporting the 9.2 data with the correct options & then using the provided script to exclude the 2.0-specific items on import.

```
# postgis_21_ext.sql:
create extension postgis;
create extension postgis_topology;
alter extension postgis update to "2.1.0";

# in this example, the old 9.2/2.0 database is "db20" & the new 9.3/2.1 database is "db21"

# backup old database
pg_dump -Fc -b -v -f "db20.bak" db20

# install latest postgis 2.1, which includes postgresql 9.3
brew update
brew uninstall geos postgis postgresql
brew install postgis

# backup 9.2 data directory
mv /usr/local/pgsql/data /usr/local/pgsql/data92

# initialize a new 9.3 data directory
mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

# start database
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

# default all new postgres databases to be postgis databases
cat postgis_21_ext.sql | psql -d template1

# new database will use the template for postgis & have the extension installed
createdb db21

# load backed up 2.0 data into new 2.1 db, stripping out 2.0 tables and functions
perl /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.0/share/postgis/postgis_restore.pl db20.bak | psql db21 2> errors.txt
```

https://gist.github.com/teeparham/6939017

references:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html
http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html

Comment: In the future, spatialize your databases using "CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS" and then the postis functions/etc won't end up included in your dump files, so you'll get marvellously clean dump/restore.

Comment: Good tip. The instructions for a previous version (1.5?) included custom scripts to add tables/functions, so I'm assuming that was the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes, 1.5 did not include extension support. 2.0+ do.